# How to check if a constant exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails (5.1) app I'm adding some decorators and dynamically extend the objects which need it.

I have basically the following structure

```
decorators  
|__ users
|     |___ active.rb
|     |___ archived.rb
|__ organizations   
      |___ active.rb
      |___ archived.rb
      |___ main.rb
```

As you may notice, the `active` and `archived` decorators are repeated for both models and they will be added to other models as well.

I have been able to make them the same so I can have a single decorator. The structure I'd like to have is

```
decorators 
|___ active.rb
|___ archived.rb
|__ organizations   
      |___ main.rb
```

The issue I'm facing now is how to know which decorator I need to extend my models with. I mean how can I determine if the decorator is just within the `Decorators` module (i.e.`Decorators::Active`) or within the `Decorators::Organizations` module (i.e. `Decorators::Organizations::Main`)?

Currently, that is static since it is always Decorators plus the pluralized name of the model.

My first idea was to use `method_missing` but that implies I have to keep duplicated files and to add something like

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)  
    Decorators::Active.send(method, *args, &block) 
end
```

within the `Decorators::Organizations::Active` decorator.

I have also looked at `const_misisng` but I haven't found a way to use it for my purpose.

Is there a "simple" way to say: use this module if exists otherwise look for this other one?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer the title you opened the question with, `defined?(Thing)` - it'll work for classes, modules, constants, etc.

An elegant way to check if something is defined within a namespace/module/you name it, `Decorators::Organizations.const_defined?("Active")`

Comment: Thanks, that should do the trick, I can also do something `Decorators::Organizations.const_defined?("Active") || Decorators::Active`.
The only problem is in development I don't eager load the code so `Active` is never defined. I suppose the only option now is to load the decorators manually in an initializer. Other ideas?  Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to eager load them if they're hanging out in `app/decorators` and are named correctly. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html see 6.1.3 "Namespaces"

Comment: Thanks. At the end, I have decided to keep multiple files and to include modules in each other so to remove duplications.